# Multiple viewports

Tags: xna, c#, viewport

[Problem solved !
I canno't answer with the response because i have less than 10 reputations. I have to wait 8 hours.]

Currently, i'm trying to display 3 viewports.

1st : This viewport is the entire screen (with `camera1` transformation, like zoom)

```
        viewportDefault = GraphicsDevice.Viewport;
```

2nd : This viewport is over the 1st viewport, but only width:400 height:200 at left bottom of the screen (with `camera2` transformation)

```
        viewport2 = new Viewport(0, 520, 400, 200);
```

3rd : This viewport is over the others, the entire screen, fond Color.Transparant. Just to display some text all over the screen, for me. (without camera transformation)

```
        viewportDevStrings = viewportDefault;
```

Here is my code :

```
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        //viewports
        viewportDefault = GraphicsDevice.Viewport;
        viewport2 = new Viewport(0, 520, 400, 200);
        viewportDevStrings = viewportDefault;
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {

                GraphicsDevice.Viewport = viewportDefault;
                DrawScene(camera1.transformation);

                if(ThisIsABool)
                {
                    GraphicsDevice.Viewport = viewport2;
                    DrawScene(camera2.transformation);
                }

                GraphicsDevice.Viewport = viewportDevStrings;
                DrawStrings();
    }
```

The problem is, when `ThisIsABool == true`, viewport2 is the entire screen...
When i look the "Watch added", here they are :

`viewportDefault    {X:0 Y:0 Width:1280 Height:720 MinDepth:0 MaxDepth:1}

viewport1   {X:0 Y:520 Width:400 Height:200 MinDepth:0 MaxDepth:1}
viewportDevStrings  {X:0 Y:0 Width:1280 Height:720 MinDepth:0 MaxDepth:1}`

Do you have some suggestions ? :(
Hope you can help...

--------------------------EDIT---------------------------

```
    public void DrawScene(Matrix transform)
    {
       DrawScene1(transform);
       DrawScene2(transform);
       DrawScene3();
    }


    public void DrawScene1(Matrix transform)
    {
       spriteBatch.Begin(
       SpriteSortMode.Deferred,
       BlendState.AlphaBlend,
       SamplerState.LinearClamp,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       transform
       );

       GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
       map_background1.Draw(spriteBatch);
       map_background2.Draw(spriteBatch);
       map_background3.Draw(spriteBatch);

       spriteBatch.End();
    }


    public void DrawScene2(Matrix transform)
    {
       spriteBatch.Begin(
       SpriteSortMode.Deferred,
       BlendState.AlphaBlend,
       SamplerState.LinearClamp,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       transform
       );

       character.Draw(spriteBatch);
       door.Draw(spriteBatch);
       monster.Draw(spriteBatch);

       spriteBatch.End();
    }


    public void DrawScene3()
    {
        BlendState blendState = new BlendState();
        blendState.ColorSourceBlend = Blend.DestinationColor;
        blendState.ColorDestinationBlend = Blend.SourceColor;

        spriteBatch.Begin(
        SpriteSortMode.Immediate,
        blendState,
        SamplerState.LinearClamp,
        null,
        null,
        null
        );

        spriteBatch.Draw(RenderTargetForShadows, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);

        spriteBatch.End();
    }
```

Comment: Can you display your `DrawScene` code. I am thinking that you may have something wrong in your spritebatch.begin method

Comment: @Jastill I edited my messagge and added the code.

Comment: i'm at work currently so I cannot create an XNA project to test any of this. (im no pro, just trying to help). this link ->  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb313965(v=xnagamestudio.10).aspx   makes me feel like you need to resize your transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...
There was a conflict with the shadow RenderTarget2D. (Nobody could fixed this problem without the shadow RenderTarget2D code i have...)

But, in doubt :
on the 1st viewport, the renderTarget2D was at the screen size, but on the 2nd viewport, i had to create an other renderTarget2D with the 2nd viewport size.

After this, i had to "generate" the 2 renderTarget2D before any draw() in viewports.